# Memory leak error from xwork2 with struts2 webapplication

Tags: memory-leaks, struts2, tomcat7, xwork

I'm able to run the application in eclipse, but once I deployed to my tomcat7 using war file I'm getting memory leak error.

kindly help me out, Thanking in advance.

**

> Log dump from tomcat7.stderr

**

```
2015-12-23 17:57:42 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized

Dec 23, 2015 5:57:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init

INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\/bin;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0/bin;C:\jython2.7.0\/bin;C:\Python27\Scripts;;.

Dec 23, 2015 5:57:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init

INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]

Dec 23, 2015 5:57:45 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init

INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]

Dec 23, 2015 5:57:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load

INFO: Initialization processed in 957 ms

Dec 23, 2015 5:57:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal

INFO: Starting service Catalina

Dec 23, 2015 5:57:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal

INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47

Dec 23, 2015 5:57:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR

INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\CareerPathFinder.war

Dec 23, 2015 5:57:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory

INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\docs

Dec 23, 2015 5:57:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory

INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\examples

Dec 23, 2015 5:57:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory

INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\host-manager

Dec 23, 2015 5:57:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory

INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\manager

Dec 23, 2015 5:57:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory

INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT

Dec 23, 2015 5:57:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start

INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]

Dec 23, 2015 5:57:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start

INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]

Dec 23, 2015 5:57:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start

INFO: Server startup in 4471 ms

Dec 23, 2015 5:58:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR

INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\SupportPortal.war

Dec 23, 2015 5:58:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body

INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://displaytag.sf.net/el is already defined

Dec 23, 2015 5:59:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause

INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]

Dec 23, 2015 5:59:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause

INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]

Dec 23, 2015 5:59:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal

INFO: Stopping service Catalina

Dec 23, 2015 5:59:01 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks

***SEVERE: The web application [/SupportPortal] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@1ac9204]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@1af5b59]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 23, 2015 5:59:01 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks***

**SEVERE: The web application [/SupportPortal] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@167b86d]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@115077e]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 23, 2015 5:59:01 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks**

**SEVERE: The web application [/SupportPortal] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@1ac9204]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@8a9f2a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Dec 23, 2015 5:59:01 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks**

***SEVERE: The web application [/SupportPortal] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@1ac9204]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@1107b71]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.***

Dec 23, 2015 5:59:01 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop***

INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]

Dec 23, 2015 5:59:06 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint shutdownExecutor

WARNING: The executor associated with thread pool [http-bio-8080] has not fully shutdown. Some application threads may still be running.

Dec 23, 2015 5:59:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop

INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

**

> pom.xml

**

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>support.portal</groupId>

  <artifactId>SupportPortal</artifactId>

  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>SupportPortal Maven Webapp</name>





  <properties>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

</properties>



<dependencies>

    <dependency>

      <groupId>junit</groupId>

      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>

      <version>3.8.1</version>

      <scope>test</scope>

    </dependency>



    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>

        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>

        <version>2.2.3</version>

        </dependency>



    <!-- MySQL database driver -->

    <dependency>

        <groupId>mysql</groupId>

        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>

        <version>5.1.9</version>

    </dependency>



    <!-- Struts 2 Hibernate Plugins -->





    <!-- Log4j logging (Struts 2 Hibernate Plugins dependency) -->

    <dependency>

                <groupId>log4j</groupId>

            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>

            <version>1.2.16</version>

        </dependency>



    <!-- Hibernate validator (Struts 2 Hibernate Plugins dependency) -->

    <dependency>

               <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>

           <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>

           <version>3.1.0.GA</version>

        </dependency>



    <!-- slf4j logging (Struts 2 Hibernate Plugins dependency) -->

    <dependency>

           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>

           <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>

           <version>1.5.6</version>

        </dependency>

                <dependency>

        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>

        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>

        <version>1.5.6</version>

        <scope>runtime</scope>

        </dependency>





    <!-- Hibernate core -->

    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>

        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>

        <version>3.2.7.ga</version>

    </dependency>



    <!-- Hibernate core library dependency start -->

    <dependency>

        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>

        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>

        <version>1.6.1</version>

    </dependency>



    <dependency>

        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>

        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>

        <version>1.0.4</version>

    </dependency>



    <dependency>

        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>

        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>

        <version>3.2.1</version>

    </dependency>



    <dependency>

        <groupId>cglib</groupId>

        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>

        <version>2.1</version>

    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate core library dependency end -->



    <!-- Hibernate query library dependency start -->

    <dependency>

        <groupId>antlr</groupId>

        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>

        <version>2.7.7</version>

    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate query library dependency end -->



    <dependency>

    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>

    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>

    <version>1.1</version>

</dependency>



<dependency>

    <groupId>javassist</groupId>

    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>

    <version>3.12.1.GA</version>

</dependency>



<dependency>

    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>

    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>

    <version>3.1.0</version>

    <optional>true</optional>

</dependency>



<dependency>

    <groupId>displaytag</groupId>

    <artifactId>displaytag</artifactId>

    <version>1.2</version>

</dependency>



<dependency>

    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>

    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>

    <version>1.4.7</version>

</dependency>











  <dependency>

    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>

    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>

    <version>3.13</version>

  </dependency>

  <dependency>

    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>

    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>

    <version>3.13</version>

  </dependency>

  <dependency>

    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>

    <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>

    <version>1.1</version>

  </dependency>

  <dependency>

    <groupId>connext</groupId>

    <artifactId>graphs</artifactId>

    <version>0.5</version>

  </dependency>

  <dependency>

    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>

    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>

    <version>2.0.1</version>

  </dependency>

  <dependency>

    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>

    <artifactId>struts2-dojo-plugin</artifactId>

    <version>2.2.3</version>

  </dependency>

  <dependency>

    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>

    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>

    <version>1.2.2</version>

  </dependency>

  <dependency>

    <groupId>ognl</groupId>

    <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>

    <version>3.0.1</version>

  </dependency>

  <dependency>

    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>

    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>

    <version>2.3.16</version>

  </dependency>

  <dependency>

    <groupId>com.opensymphony</groupId>

    <artifactId>xwork</artifactId>

    <version>2.1.2</version>

  </dependency>

</dependencies>





  <build>

    <finalName>SupportPortal</finalName>

      <plugins>

      <plugin>

        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

        <version>3.1</version>

        <configuration>

          <source>1.7</source>

          <target>1.7</target>

        </configuration>

      </plugin>



        <plugin>

        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>

        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>

        <version>2.2</version>

        <configuration>

            <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>

            <server>Tomcat</server>

            <path>/SupportPortal</path>

        </configuration>

    </plugin>



    </plugins>

  </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Don't kill you tomcat.... please. Stop it.

Comment: Sorry.
Tomcat is up and running.

Comment: `com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Container` is for internal use only